# Estimating the expected autocorrelation x time away given information about how it weakens over time

Tags: correlation, autocorrelation

Let's say I have repeated measurements of some (approximately normally distributed) variable spaced 7 days apart. Is there some way to use the information in these week-to-week correlations to estimate what the correlation is would be expected to be 3 days away (for example).

My first thought was investigating how the week-to-week correlation develop when you increase the gap from 1 to 14 to 21 etc. and fit some function post hoc. But before I go that route I wanted to understand if there's maybe some more mathematically correct/informed way to do it.

Would be happy if someone could point me in the right direction or point out some significant problem in the approach I was going to try.